# vue-chartjs - Doughnut chart with text in the middle

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I would like to add text inside the chart of Doughnut type.
I'm using this plugin in my vuejs project: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs
Currently, It's showing for all charts.
**I just want to have only Doughnut chart**, but it's show all chart.

```
//*** Doughnut chat ***//

import { Doughnut } from "vue-chartjs";
import Chart from "chart.js";

export default {
extends: Doughnut,
  data: () => ({
  chartdata: {
  labels: ["Cambodia", "Thailand", "Vietnam", "Laos"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Data One",
      backgroundColor: ["#a3c7c9", "#889d9e", "#647678", "f87979"],
      data: [91, 3, 3, 3]
      }
     ]
     },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  }
}),

mounted() {
  this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options);
  this.textCenter(880);
},
methods: {
  textCenter(val) {
    Chart.pluginService.register({
      beforeDraw: function(chart) {
        var width = chart.chart.width;
        var height = chart.chart.height;
        var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

        ctx.restore();
        var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

        var text = val;
        var textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
        var textY = height / 2;

         ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
         ctx.save();
       }
     });

     Chart.plugins.unregister(this.chartdata);
   }
 }};
 //*** end Doughnut chat ***//
```

[image]

Thank you and appreciate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than install the plugin globally with `Chart.pluginService.register` you can load it in your mounted hook of that specific chart with `this.addPlugin`:

```
mounted() {
  this.addPlugin({
    id: 'my-plugin',
    beforeDraw: function(chart) {}
  })
  this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options);
},
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/5efa8yo9/)

Comment: Hello, I am trying to get this to work in my vue3 project and I get a `addPlugin is not defined` error. Where does addPlugin come from?

Comment: @LovelyAndy I haven't tried this in vue3 yet but in the example above it is being defined by the vuechart component thats being extended. If you follow the link to the example above, you'll see that the component contains: extends: VueChartJs.Doughnut

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think I have a pretty good working version now thanks to your comment here. Great work, you saved me lots of stress.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 'tall' legend group (or not), you would like to set the text just in the middle of doughnut, not the canvas itself. So I recommend to change some vars to point to `chartArea` (the doughnut itself):

```
const width = chart.chartArea.width;
const height = chart.chartArea.height;
//...
const textY = chart.chartArea.top + height / 2;
```