# Vue Chart 3 - Doughnut Charts with Text in the Middle (Trouble registering a plugin)

Tags: vue.js, charts, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

**EDIT:** My codesandbox is working, but it's not perfect. In my actual project I've better utilized ts and am just making an if check for the charttype so the font doesn't paste on all the charts you have.
I still need to work on making the fontsize responsive and prettier, but I will try and update the codesandbox as much as I can!

If anyone would like to add to it please do! Also, post your link in the comments so anyone else having these issues can see them too!

I am attempting to make a doughnut chart that looks like this:

[image]

I've been trying to figure out how to get the code in this example using [**VueChartJS**](https://vue-chartjs.org/) ([**VueChart3**](https://github.com/victorgarciaesgi/vue-chart-3) is a TS safe rewrite of **VueChartJS** and works the same, just in composition API), but cannot figure out how to get the plugins to work properly.

[vue-chartjs - Doughnut chart with text in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60928670/vue-chartjs-doughnut-chart-with-text-in-the-middle)

[Working Example from post](https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/5efa8yo9/)

The example in the post above uses a `textCenter()` function and constantly access the context `ctx` variable. The first error I get however reads `Property 'pluginService' does not exist on type 'typeof Chart'` and also a `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register')`. I think this has to do with the way **VueChart3**  and it's `Chart.register(...registerables)` line.

I've commented out all of the code that breaks the chart currently while I try and fix this issue.
I am really stumped on where to go with this now and could really use a bit guidance.

Cheers!

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-chart-font-gk28n?file=/src/components/Chart2.vue)

**Chart2.vue**

```
<template>
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: 5rem">
    <DoughnutChart :options="options" v-bind="doughnutChartProps" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
import { computed, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { DoughnutChart, useDoughnutChart } from "vue-chart-3";
import { Chart, ChartData, ChartOptions, registerables } from "chart.js";
Chart.register(...registerables, plugin);
var plugin = function (chart) {
  var width = chart.chart.width;
  var height = chart.chart.height;
  var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

  ctx.restore();
  var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
  ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

  var text = 800;
  var textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
  var textY = height / 2;

  ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
  ctx.save();
};

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: { DoughnutChart },
  setup(props) {
    const isResponsive = ref(true);
    const getData = computed<ChartData<"doughnut">>(() => ({
      labels: ["Success"],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [10, 90],
          backgroundColor: ["#56cd92", "#f0f7ff"],
        },
      ],
    }));
    onMounted(() => {
      addPlugin({
        id: "my-plugin",
        beforeDraw: plugin,
      });
      // renderChart(chartdata, options);
      // textCenter(1000);
    });
    const options = computed<ChartOptions<"doughnut">>(() => ({
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: "bottom",
        },
      },
    }));

    const { doughnutChartProps } = useDoughnutChart({
      options,
      chartData: getData,
    });
    return {
      isResponsive,
      getData,
      options,
      doughnutChartProps,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `pluginService` is V2 syntax, to register plugins globally in V3 you can do it the same way you did with the registerables like so:

```js
Chart.register(plugin)
```

You can even do it in the same register call like so:

```js
Chart.register(...registerables, plugin)
```

**Edit:**
Plugins also have to be objects so chart.js knows which hook to use as you did in the mounted so your plugin variable has to look like this (still V2 syntax, you will need to change this yourself) to work:

```js
var plugin = {
 id: 'idOfPlugin', 
 beforeDraw: function (chart) {
  var width = chart.chart.width;
  var height = chart.chart.height;
  var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

  ctx.restore();
  var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
  ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

  var text = 800;
  var textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
  var textY = height / 2;

  ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
  ctx.save();
 };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I didn't know that pluginService was V2 syntax.
That said though, I still am getting a `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')` error when I try that. I have the plugin variable below the `Chart.register` line, so perhaps that's the issue?

I know there's plenty of things in the plugin it's that I will need to change to better fit my chart, but would I still need to call it in the `onMounted` hook right?

Sorry this is a bit scattered, but the whole implementation is way over my head

Comment: No you don't need to do it in the mounted hook, you can just call it above where you also register the registerables. But your current plugin won't work since it's also V2 syntax, for example chart.chart does not exist, second chart has to go

Comment: yeah, all of this `ctx.` code is not something I've really used before so I didn't know the difference between V2 and V3. 
With it moved up I get the error of `class does not have id: function myPlugin(chart)`. Upon googling that error I haven't gotten any real answers for the issue there. 
I'm assuming I have to call it somewhere in the setup() function since i am no longer using the `onMounted` hook
Does want me to put it into the `options` computed prop?

(Thanks so much for the help thus far. I dont mean to get you to write the whole thing for me, I just am still very new)

Comment: I didnt notice your edit last night, but thanks to you I got it working! 
Your edit still had the `chart.chart` format, but I removed that and got it to work. Cheers for all the help!